# Getting a SqlException 0x80131904, Invalid object name 'SiteToSites'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am getting a SqlException 0x80131904 while trying to fetch all records from a table. The error message is: Invalid object name 'SiteToSites'

I have looked here on Stack Overflow for this error and found lots of posts on it and answers. I've checked out the answers, but none address what I'm seeing.

There's a table in the database named SiteToSite. I am using EF Core 6, in a .NET 6 ASP.NET MVC app.

In a service class I have the following to get all the records from a table named SiteToSite:

```
        public IEnumerable<SiteToSite> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.SiteToSites.OrderBy(s => s.SiteToSiteID);
        }
```

In the controller I have the following command to call GetAll():

```
        public IActionResult Step1()
        {
            IList<SiteToSite> sites;
            sites = siteToSiteService.GetAll().ToList();
            var firstSite = sites.First() ?? new SiteToSite();
            return View(firstSite);
        }
```

The fourth line in the Step1 action method is where the error is raised.

In the DbContext class here's how the DbSet for SiteToSite is defined:

```
public virtual DbSet<SiteToSite> SiteToSites { get; set; } = null!;
```

I don't see what's wrong. There is a `SiteToSites` defined in the DbContext class. The table exists. The properties in the model class match the columns in the SQL database. And furthermore, I've got the same logic for a different table and model class, with its own GetAll() method in its service class and controller. So, why am I getting the 0x80131904 error with this class, but not with the other class?

I'm using VS 2022 and EFCore 6

Comment: After testing, there is no problem with the code you provided. Please check if your database table name is `SiteToSites`. The name of the table should be the same as what you defined in the DbContext class.

Comment: The table in the database is `SitetoSite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the code below in your DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SiteToSite>()
        .ToTable("SiteToSite");
}
```

I tested it and it works fine in my code.

If not recognized, you can try to install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`.

There is another easiest way: Define it as `SitetoSite` in DbContext class.

```
public virtual DbSet<SiteToSite> SiteToSite { get; set; } = null!;
```

And in `GetAll()`:

```
public IEnumerable<SiteToSite> GetAll()
{
    return _context.SiteToSite.OrderBy(s => s.SiteToSiteID);
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding `.ToTable("SiteToSite")` to the `modelBuilder.EntityState<SiteToSite>` call, but VS 2022 tells me that "'ModelBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ToTable'". I did add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` NuGet package to the project and added a `using` statement to include it.

Comment: I took your second approach, which is I changed the DbSet definition from `SiteToSites` to `SiteToSite`. That worked, but I'm still confused as to why. When I did the same thing to a different table, leaving it plural worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core is looking for a `SiteToSites` table but I think the correct name is `SiteToSite`.

Try configuring explicitly the name of the table SiteToSite.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SiteToSite>().ToTable("SiteToSite");
```

Comment: I did see that suggestion elsewhere, but when I tried adding the `ToTable` method call of  `modelBuilder.Entity` EF Core didn't recognize `ToTable`. There are a lot of other commands listed in the `modelBuilder.Entity` body, such as specifying the primary key, listing string lenghts, etc. Should I enter `modelBuilder.Entity<SiteToSite>().ToTable{"SiteToSite")` on another line?